# What sort of damage in a camera can cause these photos?

Tags: repair, equipment-damage, sony, bridge-camera

I've a Sony DSC-F828. Every time I use the camera, I get the following problem after several shots. I get either:

- A striped image which is overexposed even if I use a very short exposure time (ref. image 1)  [image: Image 1:A roe deer with a damaged camera]

Or:

- A predominant black image with strange colors, as if a "neon filter" is applied:
  [image: Young man planting radicchi in the garden with damaged camera].

I don't understand the cause and the origin of this problem. These are the main observations I've done:

- Shutting down the camera doesn't solve the problem
- After taking a photo the image shown in the LCD is affected by this problem (so that excludes a problem related to the CF).
- The first time it appeared was some time after I shot the sun through some leaves (?).

  Update:
- It is related with my zoom when I zoom over a certian extent I've got this problem

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the exposure (shutter, aperture, and ISO)? It appears the exposure meter might not be operating correctly.

Comment: I concur that the first shot looks kind of like a metering problem, but the second is really screwed up.  I've never seen anything like it.  May very well be damage from the high intensity light getting focused onto the sensor.  It's generally not a good idea to focus the camera directly into the sun, though if it was just a small part of the image, or was mostly obscured I wouldn't expect it to have caused serious problems.  It seems like it may be one where the best bet is to send it in for service.  Whatever it is, I doubt it is going to be user serviceable.

Comment: When  you power Off your camera, have you also removed the battery? If not, take the battery out and leave it for half an hour. Then install battery and power On your camera. Fixed?

Comment: @MichaelClark yes but don't solve the problem.

Comment: @Aj Henderson I think it will cost more than the camera...

Comment: @Esa I've tried even now the problem persist, than solve after two shots but it will reappear; even if I don't replace the battery after some time the camera works..Thanks to everybody!

Comment: Try a new memory card before you try anything else.

Comment: @Jasmine I think that if is a memory card foult I should see the right image in the LCD when I shot. I'm afraid is something else I have now find this thread in this [forum](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/36970068).

Comment: Yes that seems like a good find. However to answer your question, no. The camera writes the image to the card, then uses the card data to show you the preview. In your viewfinder you should see a normal image and the only way the viewfinder image could be messed up is if it's getting bad data. The only way the viewfinder can get bad data is if the sensor is bad or the transfer bus is bad - either way, you're not getting good data when you take a shot, and it's not something you can fix yourself.

Comment: Have you tried to take a picture with the flash? How about movies. Do they come ok?
I have the exact same problem with a samsung WB720 but it happens all the time.
But when I use the flash in a dark place, the picture gets perfect.
Also the movies in 720p are ok.
Did you found a solution?

Comment: I don't think youve ruled out the CF card. Whats showing on the camera lcd likely comes from whats stored on the card. I know if I dont have a card in I can't take a picture at all. That tells me theres no buffering in the camera.

Comment: @Jasmine In my case it depends if I use the zoom or not with zoom higher than a value the camera show this strips...

Comment: try leaving the camera off for a few *minutes*.  the ccd overheating sounds very plausible for such intermittent activity.

Comment: @Skaperen unforunately is realted to the zoom.... I don't know how...

Answer (score 9):

The first one isn't a setting/exposure issue as there are stripes/lines across the picture.

From my technical experience, I'm willing to bet it's a faulty image sensor. If you [Google images](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=faulty%20ccd%20sensor&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.51156542,d.aGc,pv.xjs.s.en_US._-554IbEZc0.O&biw=1366&bih=600&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=7vQaUp_9BYufiAfFjoHoBQ#fp=f363a312ec3b252e&hl=en&q=faulty%20ccd&tbm=isch&um=1) "faulty ccd", you can see very similar results.

This fault isn't necessarily caused by damage to the camera but just simply due to the image sensor failing.

Although I have seen a faulty shutter produce lines across the screen, this definitely looks like a CCD issue.

[This also might be an interesting read.](http://www.imaging-resource.com/badccds.html)

EDIT: Sorry, I just realised that it's intermittent? Well, I would say that the sensor is over heating. The only thing that will fix it will be to replace the CCD.